# C# Windows Form Application: How to put 5 different data in 5 different labels using a loop

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I took a `table_layout_panel` of 1 row by 5 columns and put 5 labels in all 5 columns.

Now I am trying to insert different data in these 5 labels.

For Example:-

using a for loop { print 1 to 5 }

The result should be like:-

```
    label1.Text = "1";
    label2.Text = "2";
    label3.Text = "3";
    label4.Text = "4";
    label5.Text = "5";
```

Or suggest if there is any other way to do this.
IDE: Visual studio 2019'

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as this:

```
Label[] labels =  new [] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    labels[i].Text = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More reuseably:

```
private static void SetControlText(params Control[] controls)
{
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var ctrl in controls)
    {
        ctrl.Text = (i++).ToString();
    }
}

SetControlText(new [] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 });
```

or

```
Labels[] labels = new [] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 }
SetControlText(labels);
```

Comment: You might as well call it like this: `SetControlText(label1, label2, label3, label4, label5);`.